# Kindle Fire Power Adapter Specs

Tags: charging, amazon-kindle-fire

I have misplaced the power adapter for my v1 Kindle Fire. USB charging works but is dog slow. What are the specs of its adapter, including any branding, as they're never labeled properly. Also, a photo would be very helpful, since it is likely in the box o' adapters in the basement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005CKAX82) the original stats are this:

> INPUT (AC): 100-240V, 50/60Hz
>
> OUTPUT (DC): 5V, 1.8A

Here's an image:

[image: Kindle Fire Charger]

The newer charger is 9V and 1.8A.